# scipy.optimize.linear_sum_assignment equivalent in Java

Tags: java, scipy, hungarian-algorithm

I'm trying to re-write a python algorithm to Java for some needs.

In python algorithm I have the following code :

```
row_ind, col_ind = linear_sum_assignment(cost)
```

`linear_sum_assignment` is a [scipy function](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.18.1/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.linear_sum_assignment.html)

Do you guys know an equivalent of that function in java ? I found [this one](https://github.com/KevinStern/software-and-algorithms/blob/master/src/main/java/blogspot/software_and_algorithms/stern_library/optimization/HungarianAlgorithm.java) but I didn't get the row indice and column indice in this one.

Comment: This is probably borderline off-topic (asking for libs). If you can live with the dependency, go with google's ortools.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finaly managed to do it with this [HungarianAlgorithms](https://github.com/KevinStern/software-and-algorithms/blob/master/src/main/java/blogspot/software_and_algorithms/stern_library/optimization/HungarianAlgorithm.java) and the following code :

```
// Using Hungarian Algorithm assign the correct detected measurements
// to predicted tracks
int[] assigmentL = new HungarianAlgorithm(cost).execute();
List<Integer> assigment = Lists.newArrayList(Ints.asList(assigmentL));
```

Answer (score 1):

I share an answer in kotlin, if anyone is interested, based on the same [Hungarian Algorithm](https://github.com/KevinStern/software-and-algorithms/blob/master/src/main/java/blogspot/software_and_algorithms/stern_library/optimization/HungarianAlgorithm.java):

```
val costMat = arrayOf(
    doubleArrayOf(0.5, 0.8, 0.6),
    doubleArrayOf(0.3, 0.2, 0.5),
    doubleArrayOf(0.1, 0.3, 0.7)
)
val assignmentL = HungarianAlgorithm(costMat).execute()
val assignment = listOf(costMat.indices.toList(), assignmentL.toList())
```